# Jenkins SSH User with Passphrase on Windows Slave

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, ssh

My team's currently using a Jenkins master with four different slaves; linux, two macs, and windows.
For the git clone processes with source control (gitlab) on these slaves we're using `ssh user defined with passphrase` on jenkins credentials.

All of the slaves are able to use this user on cloning the repository process but `Windows Slave`, it's giving the following error:

> stdout:
>   stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
>   Permission denied, please try again.
>   Permission denied (publickey,password).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Have you tried to use a git client on your Windows Slave directly to clone your project? This might give you a clue.

Comment: That can't be tried because I'm giving the private key and passphrase on jenkins ssh user, if I try directly on slave it'll ask for git@gitlab.com password which is meaningless

Comment: This post should explain your problem, in particular the first comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for us, that might be the possible answer but after several tries, I've managed to get connect all slaves with SSH by using the keys generated from Windows Slave, thanks.